# How to ignore errors in zgrep reader?

Tags: command-line, zgrep

I want to search a directory's contents for a certain string on Ubuntu, and output all files that contain it.
Problem: if `zgrep` tries to read a damaged file, the process stops:

```
zgrep -n 'test' /var/log/tomcat/archive/*
```

Result:

```
gzip: /var/log/tomcat/archive/my.log.gz: unexpected end of file
```

Question: how can I tell `zgrep` to ignore files that give errors?

Comment: What makes you say it stops? It shouldn't stop, are you sure it doesn't simply print the error and then continue to the next file? That's how it behaves on my system.

Comment: Are you sure it stops completely? In my tests, both `gzip`’s `zgrep` and `zutils`’ `zgrep` continue with the subsequent files.